# is moving between attached monitor and native display possible from top?

Tags: display, external-monitor

I have a laptop, connected to an external monitor which is situated right above the laptop. Is it possible to push windows from the top instead from the side as you can do in Mac?

Reference: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3694/using-external-monitor-want-mouse-to-move-up-down-not-left-right

Would love this setting in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you go to **System Settings** then **Displays**. All you have to do is drag the external monitor to the position you want it to be. So click and drag it so that it is positioned over the top of the laptop screen.

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help :)